# Store all user's login dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say that I have a website and I want to know all the users that logged in during a certain time interval.

Would it be a good idea to create a new table in the database for this purpose and add a new entry whenever a users logs in?

The table would contain 2 columns: the id of the user and the login date.

My main concern is that the number of entries from the table will become extremely large.

Can this be considered a good idea? Do you know if this method is being applied for other websites?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are banks concerned with large tables? They have millions of transactions per day? I work in the banking sector and this is not a problem.

Comment: Why not set up the system. Use JMeter to fake the heaviest load you expect and run a test. Thereby getting some metrics (response time, disk usage ....)

Comment: MySQL tables are designed for millions of records. The fact you're even asking this here tends to imply you're not going to be dealing with large quantities of data, and even if you are, sharding the table by date column is completely normal, and easily done as you will obviously be indexing the date column. .....

Comment: The bigger issue is to check if your actual setup can manage the data quantities you're expecting. How big is your user base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a table that logs all the login time of each user. If there are millions of users you might want to store the recent login time instead. If space is not a problem then it will be good to store the login time each time a user is authenticated or authorized. Like this you can archive the data in this table periodically.

Comment: You should either use some failsafe technology (replication) or periodically do a backup as a matter of course. Information is money

Comment: Database transactions are there to do this, you just have to wrap the archiving task in a transaction to make it safe.

Comment: You either need to periodically back up the data or use some failsafe technology. It has been know for hard drives to stop working

Answer (score 1):

The number of records in a table can be controlled via external script, which is put on cron/scheduler. If it becomes too big, old records can be removed

if it is not possible, as a workaround there could be a check of the number of records on each insert

just do not forget to set an index on the date field...

Comment: What is the point of storing the information in a table if all you are going to do is delete it as some arbitrary time?

Comment: I wrote 'remove' which means deletion from a source table, but it does not mean that the records could not be put to another DB for an analysis. Prod DB should be as fast as possible and not overloaded with analytical queries

Answer (score -1):

The general answer to this question is 'depends'.
You can:

- Add user to the table on login. You hit the disk for each user, so be careful with a big amount of users.
- You store a bunch of users in memory and write all the group at a certain size or time. This way you hit the disk fewer times.
- Depending on how many users you expect you can think of a no-SQL solution.

Depending on your system, I advise the 2nd o 3rd approach

Read this for more info: [Fast write performance, even if reads are very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506505/fast-write-performance-even-if-reads-are-very-slow)

Comment: You first point is incorrect. MySql and other database are able to manage a cache in memory and flush it periodically. Let the DB do the heavy lifting